# Ubuntu Google Drive Nautilus Auto Backup

Tags: ubuntu, google-drive-api, nautilus

My setup:
I am using `Nautilus (v 3.20.3)` to access `Google Drive` on a machine running `Ubuntu 16.10`.

I have a batch file that takes a daily backup of a specific `MySQL database` (using `Cron`).

My Aim: 
What I'm trying to achieve is that these backups be uploaded to a specific folder in my `Google Drive` (preferably) using `Nautilus`? Any other method would be welcome too.

Currently I'm uploading these backups manually and would prefer an automated setup.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at a CLI tool such as https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive. It will be fairly simple to integrate it to Nautilus.

This isn't really a programming question, so you'll probably get some downvotes.